# How to extract rows in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do I extract the values under a certain column that appear below a certain threshold?

This code returns True for all observations that I want to remove:

```
df['City'].value_counts()<5
```

This code returns a list of all distinct observations in the column.

```
df['City'].value_counts().index.tolist()
```

How do I combine both of these methods to get a list of 'City' values that appear less than 5 times in the dataframe?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, does `df.groupby('City').filter(lambda L: len(L) >= 5)` do what you're after? Or were you after: `df['City'].value_counts()[lambda L: L >= 5]` ?

Comment: `s=df['City'].value_counts();df.loc[df.City.isin(s[s<5].index)]`

Comment: @JonClements df['City'].value_counts()[lambda L: L >= 5] this was what I wanted. Thanks